# Large form submit causes web part error

Tags: web-part, custom-form

My form (placed on a sandboxed web part) has a people picker control that displays several hundreds users in edit mode.

At this large number of users, whenever user clicks on button or something that submit the form, web part error occurs.

I heard some where that ASP.NET forms have a limit on POST size, is it the reason?
If so, is there any workaround?

I'm on SharePoint Online.

Comment: Only the actual selected items should be getting submitted back to the server, so that *shouldn't* be an issue.  One way to check is this........Open the form that causes the error in IE, and open the IE developer tools (F12).  From the dev tools, click the 'network' tab and then click 'Start Capturing'.  Now, submit the form in a way that produces the error.  Pay attention in the logs for any POST requests, and note their size.  Post your findings in here.

Comment: Sorry for late response, this is from 
`Fiddle User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
UA-CPU: AMD64
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: _______.sharepoint.com
Content-Length: 96798
Connection: Keep-Alive`

Comment: If i'm reading that right, you're only submitting ~97KB back to the server.  That alone shouldn't cause any issues.

Comment: But when submit this form, web part error occurred, not sure but if I reduce the number of data, no more error...